# extjs4: for checkboxCmp of fieldSet

Tags: extjs, fieldset

In extjs4 ,I use FieldSet in form,and i fonud the property 'checkboxToggle',when it is true the postion of fieldSet title will appear a checkbox,that is my expected UI.
but this is not my exected:when checkbox checked the fieldset expand,and when  checkbox not checked the fieldset collapsed.
I want like  this: when checkbox checked the fieldset enable and when checkbox not checked the  fieldset disabled.
How can I do?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should mention on fieldset property

> disabled: true/false

When checked/unchecked on listeners u could modified value of **disabled**